# Theorems in classicthesis with \spacedlowsmallcaps as headerfont

Tags: small-caps, amsthm, classicthesis

I am using the `classicthesis` package and would like to add custom Theorems and Proof styles. I am also using the `amsthm` package.
Page 10 & 11 of the manual for `classicthesis` show a sample code in which the header font can be set to `\spacedlowsmallcaps`.

```
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Math Testing}
\newtheoremstyle{note}% hnamei
{3pt}% hSpace abovei
{3pt}% hSpace belowi note
{}% hBody fonti
{}% hIndent amounti1
%{\itshape}% hTheorem head fonti
{\spacedlowsmallcaps}%
{:}% hPunctuation after theorem headi
{.5em}% hSpace after theorem headi2
{}%
\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{note}{Definition}
\begin{note}
Here is a new definition
\end{note}
```

However the header in the output appears to be in a regular font. If I use the `\spacedlowsmallcaps` command outside any environment it is working fine.

Does anyone have a suggestion where the problem could be? I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011), and it does not give me any error during compilation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `\spacedlowsmallcaps` takes a mandatory argument, you can use the last argument for `\newtheoremstyle` and do the following:

```
\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{note}% hnamei
{3pt}% hSpace abovei
{3pt}% hSpace belowi note
{}% hBody fonti
{}% hIndent amounti1
%{\itshape}% hTheorem head fonti
{}%
{:}% hPunctuation after theorem headi
{.5em}% hSpace after theorem headi2
{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}}%
\theoremstyle{note}
\newtheorem{note}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some Math Testing}
\begin{note}
Here is a new definition
\end{note}
\begin{note}[A test definition]
Here is another definition
\end{note}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Stephan You're welcome! Also, welcome to TeX.SX!